# Обработать изображение из URL в SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, post, rest, spring-boot, multiple

Не совсем понимаю как можно полностью вытащить изображение по url с помощью Spring.
У меня простой REST
контроллер post

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload-multiple-files", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<FileResponse> uploadMultipleFiles(

            @RequestParam(value = "url", required = false) URL request,
            @RequestParam(value = "files", required = false) @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile[] files

    )
{//логика}
```

передаю ссылку через форму

```
<h4>Upload URL:</h4>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="@{/upload-multiple-files}">
    <p><b>URL:</b><br>
        <input type="url" name="url" size="50">
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        <input type="reset" value="Очистить"></p>
</form>
```

пришла ко мне ссылка на изображение и не очень ясно как вытащить по ссылке само изображение. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Почему вы не пользуетесь моделями как тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772857/how-to-display-jpg-from-db-web-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пошли не верным путем для решения поставленной задачи. Вам нужно загрузить файл из указанного URL. для этого не надо никаких enctype="multipart/form-data"

Все что вам надо это добавить несколько полей ввода с одним именем(хардкодом или  средствами DHTML) и отправить форму на сервер с enctype по умолчанию(то есть не устанавливая его)

так ведь input type="url" это обычное поле ввода текста, просто наделенное маской. То есть на сервер приходит все такие же строки, ничем не отличающиеся от других текстовых полей...То есть multipart/form-data, который применяется для передачи содержимого файлов с машины клиента, на сервер вам не нужен...
То есть форма будет выглядеть так:

```
<h4>Upload URL:</h4>
<form method="POST" th:action="@{/upload-multiple-files}">
    <p><b>URL:</b><br>
        <input type="urls" name="url" size="50">
        <input type="urls" name="url" size="50">
        <input type="urls" name="url" size="50">
        <input type="urls" name="url" size="50">
    </p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Отправить">
        <input type="reset" value="Очистить"></p>
</form>
```

Для обработки нескольких текстовых полей с одним именем вам нужно указать

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload-multiple-files", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<FileResponse> uploadMultipleFiles(
            @RequestParam(value = "urls", required = false) @NotEmpty String[] urls

    )
{
    foreach(String url in files) {
        URL myURL = new URL(url);
        IOUtils.copy(myURL.openStream(), new FileOutputStream("store/" + myURL.getFile()))
    }
}
```

Писал на коленке, чтобы передать суть, код возможно имеет ряд мелких неточностей относительно обработки ошибок и правил валидации.

Comment: да спасибо, но мне же нужно как то получить этот http://example.com/file.txt поэтому использовать post контроллер мне нужно а уже потом эту строку передавать как вы сказали.

Comment: а все разобрался благодарю. так же помогла эта ссылка https://medium.com/tekraze/fetch-image-from-url-in-spring-boot-java-to-upload-save-locally-6b90c2bdc2ba

Comment: и я подоспел с более полным ответом. Посмотрите пожалуйста все ли там понятно пояснил

Comment: да супер все вообще ясно теперь!